# Codeigniter sets cookie but it cannot get it

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, browser

I am using Codeigniter 3.1.6 and I am using the provided library to set a cookie.

```
$this->load->helper(array('cookie', 'url'));
    set_cookie('cookie_policy', true, '2592000', 'host', '/', '', TRUE);
```

The cookie is set correctly and I can see that in the browser. I can retrieve it but after I close my browser the cookie cant be get anymore. However, in the browser I can see it. I tried to get it with just plain PHP script but still was not not working.

Anyone have this problem before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I find works much better in vhost setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
set_cookie('cookie_policy', true, 2592000, '', '', '', TRUE);
```

If no luck add `ob_flush()` and `ob_start()` to above method

> Sometimes the value filed expecting int or string. Not sure. Just a mad idea

Comment: Apparently, for now was working. However, after I have changed it, Chrome browser starts to crash the page. On reload was okey. I have also reset the  cache. Strange issue.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/cookie_helper.html), the `expire` parameter should be an `int`:

> $expire (int) – Number of seconds until expiration

The code you show has it as a `string` - `'2592000'`.  Try:

```
set_cookie('cookie_policy', true, 2592000, 'host', '/', '', TRUE);
```